# Recordset de vba access no actualiza, solo escribe a un lado del mismo texto

Tags: vba, ms-access, update

[image: Datos repetidos al momento del update]

Tengo un form donde una persona elije a un usuario mediante un combobox y trae los datos a unos textbox para despues editar cualquiera de sus campos, pero al momento de ejecutar el codigo de edicion y revisar la tabla, los datos aparecen repetidos y yo quiero que se actualicen (remplacen).
Use el metodo de ADODB de access, pero solo escribe mas texto
Este es mi codigo, espero su ayuda porque apenas voy iniciando en esto.
Gracias de antemano.

```
Private Sub bEditar_Click()

Dim conexion As New ADODB.Connection
Set conexion = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim sql As String
sql = "Select * from Registro_usuarios where ID =" & Me.lstUs & ""
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open sql, conexion, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic


If Not rst.BOF And Not rst.EOF Then 'Verificamos si hay registros


       rst!Nombre = Me.txtEdit.Value & rst!Nombre
       rst!Usuario = Me.txtUsu.Value & rst!Usuario
       rst!Contra = Me.Txtc1.Value & rst!Contra
       rst!Nivel = Me.lstNivel & rst!Nivel
       rst.Update
       MsgBox "LOS DATOS SE CAMBIARON CON EXITO", vbInformation

        Me.lstNivel = ""
        Me.lstUs = ""
        For Each ctrl In Controls           'Limpia las cajas de texto
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then ctrl.Value = ""
        Next

End If

rst.Close 'Cierra los datos
Set rst = Nothing 'Libera memoria utilizados por los datos
conexion.Close 'Cierra la conexion
Set conexion = Nothing 'Libera memoria utilizados por la conexion

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los datos se repiten pues los estás concatenando (el valor editado con el valor existente

```
   rst!Nombre = Me.txtEdit.Value & rst!Nombre
   rst!Usuario = Me.txtUsu.Value & rst!Usuario
   rst!Contra = Me.Txtc1.Value & rst!Contra
   rst!Nivel = Me.lstNivel & rst!Nivel
```

Deberías cambiarlo por

```
   rst!Nombre = Me.txtEdit.Value
   rst!Usuario = Me.txtUsu.Value
   rst!Contra = Me.Txtc1.Value
   rst!Nivel = Me.lstNivel
```